# How to locate where an element is generated?

Tags: customization

I am trying to find where an element is generated (`<div class="slicknav_menu">`), this normally is easy, I just search on the theme folder for the class name (I normally use Grep for Windows and it "always" works), but I do not find it anywhere, at first I thought it may be generated by a plugin, but I disable them all and the element was still there, I changed to a default theme and it got removed, so I know it's generated by the theme but I am not able to find where is it.

What do you do in similar situations?

I am not sharing links to my website or the theme since I think it's more important to know how to solve similar issues in general.

Comment: maybe just search for "slicknav_menu"

Comment: That is what I search for, just the class name, nothing.

Comment: or maybe just "slicknav' which might be a general name and then _menu and other names are appended.

Comment: Thanks @Ovidiu I did locate the files that contain **slicknav**, **theme/js/jquery.slicknav.js** and **theme/js/scripts.js**, I tried to edit them, nothing happens, I deleted them nothing happens, so I basically cannot find how it's generated.

Comment: Maybe you delete something, then refresh your browser but if cache is enabled you will not see any change.

Comment: Clean cache, try private browser and it seems it's not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SlickNav](https://github.com/ComputerWolf/SlickNav) looks to be a "Responsive Mobile Menu Plugin for jQuery". Your theme probably ships with it. It's written in JavaScript so try greping for the class name `slicknav_menu` in the JavaScript files included with the theme.

As an aside, another debugging tip for next time:

Most browser dev tools allow you to disable JavaScript. If you can't find something in the PHP, try disabling JS on the page and reloading. If the *$thing* is not there anymore, it's almost certainly due to JS.

Comment: I did locate the files that contain **slicknav** as Ovidiu, **theme/js/jquery.slicknav.js** and **theme/js/scripts.js**, I tried to edit them, nothing happens, I deleted nothing happens, so I basically cannot find how it's generated.

Comment: Might be cached somewhere? Have you tried disabling JS on the page? If you figured it out by now can you add an "**Update:**" to you're question so future googlers don't have to dig :)

Comment: Disabling JS remove it, it's not cached and I simply have to move on, so I just hide it with CSS and use another menu option.

Comment: Hmm, so it's definitely in the JS. Well, when you have some time you may consider looking into [setting DOM breakpoints in Chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10827104/8015265) and that may help. But at least you have a working/temp solution, good luck :)

Comment: Nice to know, I will check that.